# How to pull the data or files from website using spoon /Kettle

Tags: web, extract, kettle

We need to pull the data from some website using peantho kettle if any one is having some pointers please let me know.
The files are in the zip  format in link available on web.

Answer (score 3):

Simple. Create a job that downloads the file from the website.

then create a transform called from the job, which loads the zipped files ( you can use text file input to read zipped text files as they are) and writes them to your db.

Comment: I need to run this from site not to download anything